# Sierpinski's construction of a non-measurable set

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, measure-theory, ho.history-overview

In the early 20th century there was a lot of fuss over the axiom of choice implying that there are Lebesgue non-measurable sets of reals. In his book about The Axiom of Choice, Gregory Moore points to the following paper:

> Sierpinski, W. **"L’axiome de M. Zermelo et son rôle dans la théorie des ensembles et l’analyse."** *Bulletin de l’Académie des Sciences de Cracovie, Classe des Sciences Math., Sér. A (1918)* (1918): 97-152.

(And even more specifically, to pages 124-125.)

Moore writes that Sierpinski proved that if $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, then there is a non-measurable set. Lebesgue argued that Sierpinski uses the axiom of choice, but Moore points out that while the assumption requires some amount of choice (as we full well know today), the implication does not.

Being a historical book about the axiom of choice, Moore doesn't provide a sketch of the proof. However, I've been unable to locate the paper. Which brings me to my question.

**Question.** Is there any accessible (preferably English) reference to what the argument of Sierpinski was?

Comment: The book [Set Theoretical Aspects of Real Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Theoretical-Analysis-Monographs-Research-Mathematics/dp/148224201X) has given several results from the mentioned paper, and I think it may also has your requested result.

Comment: Even the book says: Thus, in certain respects, the work [232] (this is the reference number to the above mentioned paper) may be regarded
as a starting point for further development of set-theoretic real analysis and,
moreover, as a prototype of the so-called reverse mathematics.

Comment: Sierpinski has many papers and a nice book on continuum that I am very interested in them, but unfortunately there is no English translation from them.

Comment: Happy to translate or paraphrase any short proofs of interest.

Comment: @Avshalom: Thank you! I'll look up the reference in the answer. If I can find it (or maybe if you can find it) and it is not in English, I'll let you know.

Comment: Ashutosh was first to market with the paraphrase.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's Sierpinski's argument: Let $h:[\mathbb{R}]^{\omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any injection. Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = h(E_x)$ where $E_x$ is the set of all reals which are at a rational distance from $x$. Note that $x - y$ is rational iff $f(x) = f(y)$. Towards a contradiction, suppose $f$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$ is also measurable and is nonzero precisely at irrationals. Let $N = \{x: g(x) > 0\}$. Note that for any rational $r$, $g(r - x) = -g(x)$ so $x \in N \iff r - x \notin N$. But this contradicts Lebesgue density theorem.

Answer (score 8):

I think the pages 249-250 are the most relevant source in ariane's pdf. Sierpinski outlines how to go from the cardinality hypothesis to the existence of a non-measurable set, as per Ashutosh's précis, although without specific reference to the Lebesgue density theorem; his proof invokes an argument about symmetry. He notes that the proof does not require Zermelo's axiom (well-ordering principle). Sierpinski proves his result for *any* function $f(x)$ satisfying the properties

$f(x) = f(y), x - y \in \mathbb{Q}, f(x) \neq f(y), x - y \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Here is a fuller rendering of Sierpinski's argument from the French:

Suppose $f : [\mathbb{R}]^{\leq \omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $E_x = \lbrace x+r : r \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$. So $E_x = E_y \Leftrightarrow x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\varphi(x)= f(E_x)$. Note $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y) \Leftrightarrow x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

*Claim*: $\varphi(x)$ is a non-measurable function. In fact, any such function $\phi(x)$ satisfying $\phi(x) = \phi(y) \Leftrightarrow x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$ is non-measurable.

Proof: Suppose $\varphi(x)$ is measurable. Then $\psi(x) = \varphi(x) - \varphi(-x)$ is also measurable, and the set $N = \lbrace x : \psi(x) > 0 \rbrace$ is a measurable set. Let $Q = \lbrace y \in Irr : y \notin N \rbrace$. Note that for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \in Irr$, of the the two numbers $x$ and $2r - x$, one belongs to $N$ and the other to $Q$ (since $\psi(2r - x) = -\psi(x)$ for irrational $x$, while for rational $x, \psi(x) = 0$). So $N$ and $Q$ are symmetric images of each other, when one takes any point with rational abscissa as centre of symmetry.

Now let $(a,b)$ be any interval, and suppose $N \cap (a, b)$ is measurable. Let $(a_1, b_1)$ be an interval with rational endpoints such that $(a_1, b_1) \subseteq (a,b)$. Let $N_1 = N \cap (a_1, b_1), Q_1 = Q \cap (a_1, b_1)$. $N_1$ and $Q_1$ are measurable, being symmetric images and so have the same measure, which is half the length of the interval $(a_1, b_1)$, since the points in $(a_1, b_1)$ belonging neither to $N$ nor $Q$ are countably many.

So one can decompose $(a,b)$ into two sets which have the same measure on each rational interval. It follows easily (without using the axiom of Mr Zermelo) that we have reached a contradiction. So $\varphi$ cannot be measurable.

Comment: If you want to be correct, $[\Bbb R]^{\aleph_0}$, since $|\Bbb R|^{\aleph_0}=|\Bbb R|$ requires no choice whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

A reprint of the mentioned paper can be found in: W. Sierpinski, Oeuvres choisies Tome II, PWN--Editions Sci. Pologne, Warszawa, 1975,
pp. 208-255

Answer (score 5):

The three volumes of Sierpinski's Oeuvres Choisies can be found [here](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/) (scroll down to Sierpinski). The article (in French) is on pages 106ff of [this pdf](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Sierpinski%20Oeuvres%20Choisies%20II.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a transcript of the relevant part of the text:

> Remarquons que l'on peut démontrer, sans l'aide de l'axiome de M. Zermelo, le théorème de M. J Konig d'après lequel la puissance du continu n'est pas $\aleph_\omega$. Cela résulte de ce que l'hypothèse suivante: la puissance du continu est $\aleph_\omega$, contient l'hypothèse que voici: le continu peut être regardé comme un ensemble bien ordonné; cette hypothèse, sans un appel à un nouvel axiome, justifie tous les choix nécessaires pour le raisonnement ultérieur.
>
> On peut démontrer, sans que l'on ait à appliquer l'axiome de M. Zermelo, que l'ensemble de toutes les suites infinies des nombres réels a la puissance du continu; mais on ne sait pas démontrer sans l'aide de cet axiome que l'ensemble de tous les sous-ensembles dénombrables du continu a la puissance du continu. En effet, pour démontrer ce dernier théorème, on divise en classes toutes les suites infinies, en rangeant dans une même classe .toutes les suites qui ne différent que par l'ordre de leurs termes et l'on choisit une suite de chacune de ces classes. Or on peut démontrer, sans avoir recours à l'axiome du choix, que l'ensemble de tous les sous- ensembles finis du continu a la puissance du continu; on le peut grâce à ce que le continu peut être ordonné. On peut aussi démontrer, sans l'aide de l'axiome de M. Zermelo, que l'ensemble de tous les sous-ensembles d'un ensemble dénombrable a la puissance dil continu.
>
> On ne sait pas démontrer sans l'aide de cet axiome que, si $P_1,P_2,P_3,\ldots$ et
>   $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,\ldots$ sont deux suites infinies d'ensembles sans éléments communs deux à deux telles que, pour tout $n$ naturel, l'ensemble $P_n$ ait la même puissance que l'ensemble $Q_n$,l'ensemble-somme $S = P_1+P_2+P_3+\cdots$ a la même puissance que l'ensemble-somme $T = Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+\cdots$ Pour démontrer ce théorème, on considère, pour tout $n$ naturel, une correspondance biunivoque entre $P_n$ et $Q_n$; or il existe en général une infinité de telles correspondances entre deux ensembles ayant même puissance; ainsi, chaque fois, il faudra en choisir une. La définition de la somme d'une série infinie de nombres cardinaux est basée sur le théorème cité; par conséquent nous ne savons pas introduire la notion de la somme d'une série de nombres cardinaux sans nous appuyer sur l'axiome de M. Zermelo. La même remarque concerne la notion du produit infini de nombres cardinaux.
>
> En particulier, les formules 
>   $$\begin{aligned}
> 2+2+2+\cdots &= \aleph_0 \\
> \aleph_0+\aleph_0+\aleph_0+\cdots &= \aleph_0 \\
> 2^{\aleph_0}+2^{\aleph_0}+2^{\aleph_0}+\cdots &= 2^{\aleph_0}
> \end{aligned}$$ ne peuvent être démontrées sans l'appui de l'axiome de M. Zermelo. Sans l'invoquer on ne sait non plus démontrer que la somme d'une infinité effectivement énumérable d'ensembles effectivement énumérables est un ensemble dénombrable. (Nous appelons, d'après M. Borel, un ensemble $E$ effectivement énumérable lorsque nous savons établir au moins une loi d'après laquelle, à tout élément de $E$, correspond un nombre naturel bien déterminé et réciproquement. Un ensemble est dit dénombrable lorsqu'on sait seulement qu'au moins une loi pareille existe. On ne connaît d'ailleurs aucun exemple individuel d'un ensemble dénombrable qui ne soit pas effectivement énumérable). En effet, soit $E_1, E_2,E_3,\ldots$ une suite infinie donnée d'ensembles effectivement énumérables. Donc, pour tout $n$ naturel nous saxons au moins d'une manière ranger l'ensemble $E_n$ en me suite infinie; pour en déduire la suite double qu'on transforme ensuite par la méthode des diagonales en une suite simple, il faut choisir pour tout $n$ une suite infinie formée de tous les éléments de $E_n$. Si l'on a une suite infinie $E_1, E_2,E_3,\ldots$ d'ensembles effectivement énumérables et si l'on sait définir une loi d'après laquelle, à tout nombre naturel $n$, correspond une suite infinie bien déterminée contenant tous les éléments de $E_n$, l'ensemble-somme $E_1+E_2+E_3+\cdots$ est effectivement énumérable.
>
> Nous pouvons même démontrer que le théorème d'après lequel l'ensemble-somme d'une infinité dénombrable d'ensembles dénombrables est lui-même dénombrable, entraîne l'axiome de M. Zermelo pour toute infinité dénombrable d'ensembles dénombrables. Admettons, en effet, le théorème suivant: l'ensemble-somme d'une infinité dénombrable d'ensembles dénombrables est dénombrable; soit $P_1,P_2,P_3,\ldots$ une suite infinie d'ensembles déombrables sans éléments communs deux à deux. Posons $S = P_1+P_2+P_3+\cdots$ D'après le théorème que nous venons d'admettre, l'ensemble $S$ est dénombrable; il existe par conséquent une suite infinie $u_1,u_2,u_3,\ldots$ formée de tous les éléments de $S$. Pour tout $n$ naturel désignons par $u_{k_n}$, le premier terme de cette suite appartenant à $P_n$; la suite $u_{k_1},u_{k_2},u_{k_3},\ldots$ contiendra évidemment un et un seul élément de tout ensemble $P$, $(n= 1,2,3,\ldots)$.
>
> Ainsi, admettre, dans un cas particulier, l'exactitude de l'axiome de M. Zermelo est nécessaire pour démontrer la dénombrabilité d'une somme d'une infinité dénombrable d'ensembles dénombrables. Nous pouvons indiquer un autre cas particulier du même axiome qui suffit à lui seul pour démontrer le théorème considéré. C'est l'axiome de M. Zermelo appliqué à toute infinité dénombrable d'ensembles de puissance du continu. Cela résulte de ce qu'il existe toujours une infinité de la puissance du continu de correspondances biunivoques entre deux ensembles dénombrables.
>
> Remarquons d'autre part que nous ne savons même pas démontrer, sans l'aide de l'axiome de M. Zermelo, que le continu ne puisse être décomposé en une infinité dénombrable d'ensembles dénombrables; ni même qu'une somme d'une infinité dénombrable d'ensembles dénombrables ne puisse avoir de puissance supérieure à celle du continu. Cependant nous savons démontrer, sans avoir recours à l'axiome de M. Zermelo, que $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0 = \aleph_0$. D'autre part, nous ne savons pas démontrer, sans faire appel à cet axiome, que le continu ne puisse être décomposé en une infinité de puissance supérieure à celle du continu d'ensembles non vides.
>
> Nous ne savons pas démontrer, sans faire appel à l'axiome de M. Zermelo, que, si $M$ est un ensemble de puissance $\mathfrak{m}$ dont les éléments sont des ensembles $P$ de puissance $\mathfrak{n}$, sans éléments communs, et si $N$ est un ensemble de puissance $\mathfrak{n}$ dont les éléments sont des ensembles $Q$ de puissance $\mathfrak{m}$ sans éléments communs, la somme $S$ de tous les ensembles $P$ constituant $M$ ait la même puissance que la somme $T$ de tous les ensembles $Q$ constituant $N$, et que chacune de ces sommes ait la puissance $\mathfrak{mn}$.<sup>18</sup>
>
> En particulier, nous ne savons pas démontrer, sans invoquer l'axiome de M. Zermelo, que la somme d'une infinité dénombrable d'ensembles de la puissance du continu ait la même puissance que la somme d'une infinité de puissance du continu d'ensembles dénombrables, ni que chacune de ces sommes ait la puissance du continu; et cependant, sans faire interenir l'axiome de M. Zermelo, nous sommes en mesure de démontrer que $$2^{\aleph_0} \cdot\aleph_0 = \aleph_0 \cdot 2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}.$$
>
> De même, nous ne savons pas démontrer, sans l'aide de cet axiome, qu'une somme d'une infinité de puissance du continu d'ensembles de puissance du continu est un ensemble de puissance du continu, malgré que nous sachions démontrer sans cet aide que le continu peut être décomposé en une infinité de puissance du continu d'ensembles de puissance du continu, et que la formule $2^{\aleph_0}\cdot2^{\aleph_O}=2^{\aleph_0}$ subsiste.
>
> Observons encore que, sans nous appuyer sur l'axiome de M. Zermelo, nous ne savons pas démontrer le théorème suivant: si l'ensemble $S$ est une somme d'me infinité dénombrable d'ensembles $S = E_1+E_2+E3+\cdots$ et si l'ensemble $T$, pour tout $n$ naturel, a une puissance non inférieure à celle de l'ensemble $S_n = E_1+E_2+\cdots+E_n$, l'ensemble $T$ ne
>   peut avoir de puissance inférieure à celle de l'ensemble $S$.<sup>19</sup>
>
> Les démonstrations des inégalités qui se rapportent aux nombres cardinaux font appel, à plusieurs reprises, à l'axiome de M. Zermelo. Nous ne savons pas démontrer sans l'aide de cet axiome que, par exemple,
>   pour les nombres cardinaux $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}, \mathfrak{m}_1, \mathfrak{n}_1$, les inégalités $$\mathfrak{m} < \mathfrak{n} \quad\text{et}\quad \mathfrak{m}_1 < \mathfrak{n}_1$$ entraînent l'inégalité $$\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}_1 < \mathfrak{n} + \mathfrak{n}_1,$$ ou quelles entraînent l'inégalité $\mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{m}_1 < \mathfrak{n}\mathfrak{n}_1$; ou bien qu'elles entraînent l'inégalité $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}_1 < \mathfrak{n}\mathfrak{n}_1$. On peut cependant démontrer, en évitant tout appel à cet axiome, que les inégalités $\mathfrak{m} \leq \mathfrak{n}$ et $\mathfrak{m}_1 \leq \mathfrak{n}_1$ entraînent les inégalités $$\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}_1 \leq \mathfrak{n} + \mathfrak{n}_1, \quad \mathfrak{m}\cdot\mathfrak{m}_1 \leq \mathfrak{n}\cdot \mathfrak{n}_1, \quad \mathfrak{m}^{\mathfrak{m}_1} \leq \mathfrak{n}^{\mathfrak{n}_1}.$$ ainsi que, pour tous les nombres cardinaux $\mathfrak{m}$ et $\mathfrak{m}_1$, que les inégalités $$2^{\mathfrak{m}} > \mathfrak{m}, \quad \mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}_1 \geq \mathfrak{m}, \quad \mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{m}_1 \geq \mathfrak{m},$$ subsistent; enfin que, pour les nombres cardinaux non finis, l>'inégalité $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}_1 \lt \mathfrak{m}\cdot\mathfrak{m}_1$ est vérifiée.<sup>20</sup>
>
> Nous ne savons non plus démontrer sans l'aide de l'axiome de M. Zermelo qu'une somme de deux nombres cardinaux non finis ne peut être en même temps supérieure à chacun de ces deux nombres<sup>21</sup> M. S. Lesniewski a observé que de ce théorème résulte, sans l'aide de l'axiome de M. Zermelo, la *trichotomie* (c'est-à-dire le théorème d'après lequel deux nombres cardinaux quelconques peuvent être réunis par l'un des signes suivants $\gt,=,\lt$).
>
> Admettons, en effet, le théorème en question. Soient $\mathfrak{m}$ et $\mathfrak{n}$ deux nombres cardinaux donnés. Il suffira, évidemment de considérer le cas où les nombres dont il s'agit ne sont pas finis puisque, dans le cas contraire, la trichotomie est immédiate. D'après le théorème que nous venons d'admettre, on ne peut avoir à la fois $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n} \gt \mathfrak{m}$ et $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n} \gt \mathfrak{n}$; il subsiste donc au moins l'une des égalités $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n} = \mathfrak{m}$ et $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n} = \mathfrak{n}$ dont la première donne $\mathfrak{m} \geq \mathfrak{n}$; la seconde donne $\mathfrak{m} \leq \mathfrak{n}$.
>
> Quant à la trichotomie, observons que nous ne savons pas la démontrer d'une autre manière qu'en nous appuyant sur le *théorème de M. Zermelo* d'après lequel, pour tout ensemble $E$, un ensemble bien ordonné existe ayant la même puissance que l'ensemble $E$ (*Wohlordfiungssatz*); et c'est précisément à cause de ce théorème que M. Zermelo a introduit son axiome du choix<sup>22</sup>. La même remarque s'applique à la démonstration des formules $$\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m} + \mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}\cdot\mathfrak{m}, \quad 2^{\mathfrak{m}} = \mathfrak{m}^{\mathfrak{m}}$$ pour tous les nombres cardinaux non finis $\mathfrak{m}$.<sup>23</sup>
>
> Une question assez délicate qui se pose lorsqu'on considère une
>   infinité de nombres cardinaux, mérite notre attention. Une suite infinie de nombres cardinaux $$\mathfrak{m}_1,\mathfrak{m}_2,\mathfrak{m}_3,\ldots$$
>   étant donnée, peut-on, sans être obligé de recourir à l'axiome de M. Zermelo, considérer comme existante une suite infinie d'ensembles $$M_1,M_2,M_3,\ldots$$
>   où la puissance de l'ensemble $M_n$ est $\mathfrak{m}_n$,pour $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$?
>
> La réponse peut paraître douteuse puisqu'il existe toujours une infinité d'ensembles ayant le même nombre cardinal; or on peut se demander: peut-on définir un nombre cardinal $\mathfrak{m}$ autrement qu'en déterminant un ensemble de puissance $\mathfrak{m}$?

Answer (score 0):

Sierpiński's argument is the following.

If $[\mathbb{R}]^{\aleph_0}$ has size $2^{\aleph_0}$ then there is an injection $f:[\mathbb{R}]^{\aleph_0} \to \mathbb{R}$. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the Vitali class $x + \mathbb{Q}$ belongs to $[\mathbb{R}]^{\aleph_0}$. Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\phi(x) = f(x + \mathbb{Q})$. This function $\phi$ cannot be measurable. In fact, no function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = f(x') \iff x-x' \in \mathbb{Q}$ can be measurable.

Sierpiński's proof of this fact proceeds by first defining $\psi(x) = \phi(x)-\phi(-x)$. Note that $\psi(x) = 0 \iff x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Moreover, for any rational $q$ and irrational $x$, $$\psi(2q-x) = \phi(2q-x) - \phi(x-2q) = \phi(-x) - \phi(x) = -\psi(x).$$ It follows that the sets $N = \{x : \psi(x) > 0\}$ and $P = \{x : \psi(x) < 0\}$ are symmetric about every rational point $q$.

From this, we see that if $N$ and $P$ were measurable, they would both occupy half of every interval $(a,b)$ with rational endpoints. [Reflect $N \cap (a,b)$ about the midpoint $(a+b)/2$ to obtain $P \cap (a,b)$. Since reflections are measure preserving, we see that $\mu(N \cap (a,b)) = \mu(P \cap (a,b))$. Since $N \cup P$ contain every irrational number and $N \cap P = \varnothing$, we also have $\mu(N \cap (a,b)) + \mu(P \cap (a,b)) = b-a$. Therefore $\mu(N \cap (a,b)) = \mu(P \cap (a,b)) = (b-a)/2$.] It follows, using rational approximations, that $N$ and $P$ occupy half of every interval of $\mathbb{R}$, which is impossible by Lebesgue density.